# How to compress some file on another website directory with php

Tags: php, zip

I want to create a zip file, the content of the file was retrieved from another website. For example I have file:

http://examples.com/path/file.txt

and I want to download `file.txt` as a zip file. I tried with `file_get_contents();` but it's not working.

```
$content = file_get_contents(http://examples.com/path/file.txt);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('config.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString(file.txt, $content);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

I think it will get the content of `file.txt`, and create a compressed zip file, but when i open the output file it is not (incomplete sentence).

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the path to the file? It is a string after all. Also, instead of saying "It is not working", try to be more specific. Do you get the `Failed` feedback? Do you get any output? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `gzencode()` if you need just 1 file compression :

```
// dump & compress
$file = '/tmp/image.png.gz';
$content = file_get_contents('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/aff/bbb');
$compr = gzencode($content, 9);
file_put_contents($file, $compr);

// download
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Keep in mind that there can be various file permissions / isolation problems. For example by default Ubuntu isolates `/tmp` folder for a PHP process. If you want /tmp folder for a PHP process to be **global** - you must set [PrivateTmp](https://serverfault.com/questions/614781/php-script-cant-access-tmp-folder) feature to `FALSE`.